# How can I distinguish my characters in a vector? SFML 2.4.1

Tags: c++, sfml, push-back

I am using push_back to add identical characters and for some reason these characters all have the same stats all the time.

Battle.cpp:

```
void Battle::InitalizeUser() 
{

    user.t_Pokemon.clear();
    user.t_Item.clear();

    user.currentPokemon_U = 0;

    user.t_Pokemon.push_back(&uF1);
    user.t_Pokemon.push_back(&uF1);
    user.t_Pokemon.push_back(&uW3);
    user.t_Pokemon.push_back(&uW3);
    user.t_Pokemon.push_back(&uG5);
    user.t_Pokemon.push_back(&uG5);

    user.t_Item.push_back(&uI1);
    user.t_Item.push_back(&uI2);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < user.t_Pokemon.size(); i++)
    {
        user.t_Pokemon.at(i)->poke_health = 100;
        user.t_Pokemon.at(i)->poke_isFainted = false;
    }

    assert(user.t_Pokemon.size() == 6);

    assert(user.t_Item.size() == 2);
}
```

So if uF1 health is reduced all uF1 characters will suffer the same reduction, but I don't want all the others uF1 to suffer the reduction, I want to be able to distinguish them and have only one specific character affected.

How can I do that?

Pokemon.cpp:

```
void Pokemon::attackNormal(Pokemon * opponentPokemon)
{

    opponentPokemon->poke_health = opponentPokemon->poke_health - 20;
    opponentPokemon->changeIfFainted();

    assert(opponentPokemon->poke_health <= 100 && opponentPokemon->poke_health >= 0);

}
```

Battle.h:

```
class Battle
```

{
private:

```
static Trainer user;
static Trainer ash;


static IntRect user_Rect;
static IntRect ash_Rect;

// User's pokemon
static Fire uF1;
static Water uW3;
static Grass uG5;
static Item uI1;
static Item uI2;
```

}

uF1 : Pokemon.h

```
   class Fire : public Pokemon
```

{

```
public:
 Fire(); 
 Fire(string name); 
 virtual ~Fire();
void specialAttack(Pokemon * opponentPokemon);
void changeWeather();
void Draw(RenderWindow &window);
```

};

Comment: you should show the code that is responsible for reducing health too... and btw why do you duplicate pointers in the vector?

Comment: In order to not  have to create a uF2, uF3...

Comment: We need a [mcve].  In particular, what is the declaration of `user.t_pokemon` and `uF1`, `uW3` etc?

Comment: If you don't create new objects, then you only have one object.  If you modify it ... you have modified it.

Comment: Just guessing, because the sample code is missing so many parts, but `&uF1` **always** points at `uF1`, so changing `user.t_Pokemon[0]` changes `uF1`, and you'll see those changes when you access it through `user.t_Pokemon[0]`and `user.t_Pokemon[1]`, because they both point at the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your vector contains copies of a pointer what is not equivalent to having different copies of an actual object.

It seems that you are passing same pointers several times in order to achieve object copy which is not a case.

You should first declare all your objects and then add their addresses to the vector.

Additional note: you don't have to create a variable for every object you use. You could also create an array of objects.

Comment: Thank you. I fix it, I just changed to static Fire uF1 [5]